# Best way to create member pages for a lab website?

Tags: plugins, pages, members

I lab I work for - implab.hu - would like to move migrate to a wordpress type site, but I have yet to find a similar plugin or template that imitates the function visible at http://implab.hu/Members where you can see a link for each lab members profile, and afterwards as you click on it you are redirected to a Members style template page for their CVs.

I was wondering whether there is any elegant way to achieve this in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you're looking for is **[Buddypress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/)**!

With Buddypress you can have member profiles, activity streams, user groups, messaging, and more. With this plugin you can create a specific field or textarea called CV that will be outputed on the user's profile pages, this way your users can fill their CV by themselves.

If you're looking to just create pages instead of a social networking website, you can just create pages within Wordpress instead, and build this type of styling with CSS, here's an explanation on **[how to create pages on Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Pages)**